# ¿Cómo resolver este error: CANNOT ADD FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT (1215)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Os pongo en contexto(MySQL):

Tengo una tabla llamada `users` cuyo código de creación es el siguiente y **funciona**:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USERNAME` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `posX` DOUBLE DEFAULT '1722.9358',
  `posY` DOUBLE DEFAULT '-1900.2704',
  `posZ` DOUBLE DEFAULT '13.5646',
  `posAng` DOUBLE DEFAULT '99.8835',
  `MONEY` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ARMOUR` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
  `HEALTH` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `LEVEL` INT(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `SALT` VARCHAR(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SKIN` INT(11) DEFAULT '250',
  `DEATH` BINARY(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `SLOT_0` INT(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `SLOT_1` INT(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `SLOT_2` INT(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `SLOT_3` INT(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `SLOT_4` INT(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `SLOT_5` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `SLOT_6` INT(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `SLOT_8` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `SLOT_9` INT(4) DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY(ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Como **cada** usuario puede tener varios vehículos, y un vehículo sólo puede tener un usuario o propietario (relación 1:N) quiero crear una segunda tabla llamada `vehicles` con una foreign key que enlace el `propietario` de la tabla `vehicles`, con el `ID` de la tabla `users`, el código de la tabla `vehicles`es el siguiente y **no funciona, da error al añadir clave foránea**:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `vehicles`;

CREATE TABLE `vehicles` (
  `ID_v` INT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `posX` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
  `posY` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
  `posZ` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
  `posAng` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
  `color1` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `color2` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `respawn` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT '-1',
  `propietario` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(`ID_v`),
 INDEX(`propietario`),
 CONSTRAINT FK1 FOREIGN KEY (`propietario`)REFERENCES `users`(`ID`) 
 ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: puedes indicar exactamente el error que te da?

Comment: Veo dos problemas a simple viste, Owner en la tabla vehicles puede ser null y en la otra tabla no (lo cual violaria la referencia de foreign key). Ademas, owner deberia ir a parar a la primary key de la tabla users, porque si no, que pasa cuando cambies el nombre en la tabla users?

Answer (score 2):

Al momento con las creaciones de tablas que tienes deberías estar recibiendo un error similar a este:

> Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'vehicles_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'users'

Lo anterior en razón de que la columna `USERNAME` al no ser una llave primaria entonces no esta indexada; lo anterior se pudiera arreglar así:

```
ADD INDEX(USERNAME);
```

Sin embargo considera que de acuerdo con [la doc. de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/primary-key-optimization.html) una llave primaria con un valor auto incremental será mas rápida y ayudará en parte al rendimiento de tus consultas;  pues cada número representa de forma única a una fila de datos.

Sin embargo tienes una llave primaria compuesta por 2 columnas; tanto:

- `ID`
- `USERNAME`

**Observaciones**

- En este punto lo mejor sería que `USERNAME` tenga un `CONSTRAINT` de tipo `UNIQUE`para por ejemplo impedir valores duplicados.
- Que el `ID` de la tabla `users` apunte a la columna `OWNERS` la cual en lugar de ser tipo `VARCHAR` sea de tipo `INT`
- Deja como única llave primaria en `users` a la columna `id`

Lo anterior en razón de que una llave primaria debería ser un valor único que así mismo identifique cada fila de datos; entonces elegir el `USERNAME` no asegura que este valor lo sea.

Entonces para la tabla `users` tu columna `USERNAME` la dejarías como:

```
USERNAME VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE;
```

Y para indexar los resultados de búsqueda de esta columna sería:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX busqueda_users (USERNAME);
```

Finalmente en la tabla `vehicles` dejala como:

```
`OWNER` INT(10) NOT NULL, 
 FOREIGN KEY (`OWNER`)REFERENCES `users`(`ID`)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! Voy a hacer lo que me has dicho, llevaba tiempo sin manejar bases de datos y no recordaba esas cosas pero me has refrescado la memoria :D

Comment: Me sigue dando error al añadir clave foránea (1215), edito el post con el codigo nuevo de la tabla 1 y 2

Answer (score 0):

Vale ya lo arreglé, el problema esque **propietario era not null**, y luego se intentaba on update cascade **on delete set null** había una contradicción y no dejaba crear la FK.